# How to display text value inserted using Hibernate in pgAdmin3?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, pgadmin

I have a table, which has a column "description" of type TEXT. If I do:

`SELECT id, description FROM table_name;`

I see in "description" column instead of text value a number. Is there any way to see the text value?

Edit: After some testing I found out why I see numbers, but others like Craig see real text. It's because the data are inserted using Hibernate.

Entity:

`@Entity
public class Settings {`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String key;

@Lob
@Column(nullable = false, length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
private String value;
```

// getters and setters

}

Log result:

`Hibernate: create table Settings (id int4 not null, key varchar(255) not null, value text not null, primary key (id));`

Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into Settings (key, value, id) values (?, ?, ?)
16:05:32,718 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [GoogleSiteVerification]
16:05:32,718 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [CLOB] - []
16:05:32,726 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [4]

If I do in pgAdmin3 this select:

`select * from settings;`

I see this result:

`1;"GoogleSiteVerification";"112351"`

Comment: Unless I had some seriously impressive psychic powers I couldn't answer this one without at *least* a copy and paste of the actual query output (try running it in `psql` then copying query and output) ... or at least the table definition and a few records from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")` to attribute annotated with `@Lob`. Now it works as desired.

Also it solved the issue with encoding, which was the reason I opened pgAdmin in the first place (to see what's inside).

Technical detail: PostgreSQL stored LOB in separate place and referenced it by a numerical identifier (which was what the number which confused me).

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id integer, description text);

INSERT INTO table_name(id, description) values (1, '12');
```

Demo:

```
testdb=> SELECT id, description FROM table_name;
 id | description 
----+-------------
  1 | 12
(1 row)
```

Yup, I'd say you have a number in your *description* column because there's a number in your description column.